# VS code not loading Python Interpreter

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, anaconda

Here is my VS code infor:

```
Version: 1.43.2 (user setup)
Commit: 0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50
Date: 2020-03-24T07:38:38.248Z
Electron: 7.1.11
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

My python path is here:

```
/auto/energymdl2/anaconda3/envs/commod_py3_20200921/bin/python
```

But VS codes keeps saying **Select Python Interpreter** in the status bar even after I selected.
[image]

But when I try to select, it says it is already being selected. At moment, due to this, I am unable to use Python linter Flake8.
[image]

When I check the console log. I got the following.

```
Error Python Extension: 2020-09-23 05:02:01: Failed to parse interpreter information for /auto/energymdl2/anaconda3/envs/commod_py3_20200921/bin/python,/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.5.86806/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py,/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.5.86806/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py stderr: Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sdlc'
```

But when I go into Python and import **sdlc**. I am able to.
Python/iPython path:

```
/auto/energymdl2/anaconda3/envs/commod_py3_20200921/bin/python
```

[image]
Here is what I have in my setting.json

```
{
  "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": false,
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.flake8Args": [
    "--ignore=W605",
    "--ignore=W503",
    "--ignore=W605",
    "--max-line-length=120"
  ],
  "python.linting.banditEnabled": false,
  "python.pythonPath": "/auto/energymdl2/anaconda3/envs/commod_py3_20200921/bin/python",
  // "python.condaPath": "/auto/energymdl2/anaconda3/envs/commod_py3_20200727/bin/python"
}
```

Comment: 1. In your workspace you should have a `.vscode` folder and in that a `.settings` file (name may be a bit different, recalling from memory). In there is should say what your used python interpreter path is. 2. You have multiple python version installed. You can check the path of your python interpreter with `which python` (or `which ipython`). In your VSC commando (second picture) select "Enter interpreter path..."

Comment: Just added .json and python path. Yeah, I have multiple python interpreter installed. But the path are correct. It's working fine before.

Comment: Did you consult the relevant [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) ? If I understand correctly, `python.condaPath` should be the path to the *Conda executable*, not the Python installation in an environment. Setting the `python.pythonPath` to the Python in the environment might not be sufficient for it to work correctly, either.

Comment: @AMC Yeah, I am pointing to the executable. I think you might be referring to python.exe file? That's understand Windows. In Linux, it is just python.

Comment: _I think you might be referring to python.exe file? That's understand Windows. In Linux, it is just python._ Which part of my comment are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that there is some logic goes into `$your_conda_env_path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sitecustomize.py` that imports user-defined packages in working repo. But the working directory env variable was not set properly. I created a .env file under repo root dir and added relevant env variables. It resolved the issue.

So in fact all the conda envs were detected. It is just when it tries to load them, it hits ModuleNotFoundError.